# Modificando o Material Angularjs Start criando novo modulo/controller

Tags: angularjs

peguei o código  do Material Angularjs Start para ver como funciona, removi o controller User e estou tentando programar meu próprio Controller, mas esta dando um baita erro e o layout não carrega, gostaria de saber o que estou fazendo de errado, seguem os códigos:

index.html:

```
<body ng-app="starterApp" layout="row" ng-controller="ChartController as chart" >
  <md-sidenav class="site-sidenav md-sidenav-left md-whiteframe-z2" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-sm')">
    <md-toolbar class="md-whiteframe-z1">
      <h1>Gráficos</h1>
    </md-toolbar>
    <md-list>
      <md-list-item >
          <md-button >
            ///
          </md-button>
      </md-list-item>
    </md-list>
  </md-sidenav>
<div flex layout="column" tabIndex="-1" role="main" class="md-whiteframe-z2">
    <md-toolbar layout="row" class="md-whiteframe-z1">
      <md-button class="menu" aria-label="Show User List">
        <md-icon md-svg-icon="menu" ></md-icon>
      </md-button>
      <h1>Wolk</h1>
    </md-toolbar>

    <md-content flex id="content">
        <md-icon class="avatar"></md-icon>
        <h2>aa</h2>
        <p>bb</p>

        <md-button class="contact" aria-label="Contact User">
          <md-tooltip>Contact</md-tooltip>
          <md-icon md-svg-icon="share"></md-icon>
        </md-button>
      </md-content>

  </div>
<!-- All -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/generated-all.js"></script>

<!--     <script src="./src/users/Users.js"></script>
<script src="./src/users/UserController.js"></script>
<script src="./src/users/UserService.js"></script> -->

<!-- 
<script src="./src/charts/Charts.js"></script>
<script src="./src/charts/ChartController.js"></script> 
-->

<script type="text/javascript">

      angular
          .module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'charts'])
          .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider){

              /* $mdIconProvider
                  .defaultIconSet("./assets/svg/avatars.svg", 128)
                  .icon("menu"       , "./assets/svg/menu.svg"        , 24)
                  .icon("share"      , "./assets/svg/share.svg"       , 24)
                  .icon("google_plus", "./assets/svg/google_plus.svg" , 512)
                  .icon("hangouts"   , "./assets/svg/hangouts.svg"    , 512)
                  .icon("twitter"    , "./assets/svg/twitter.svg"     , 512)
                  .icon("phone"      , "./assets/svg/phone.svg"       , 512); */

                  $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                      .primaryPalette('brown')
                      .accentPalette('red');

          });

</script>
</body>
```

Charts.js

```
(function(){
  'use strict';

   // Prepare the 'charts' module for subsequent registration of controllers and delegates
    angular.module('charts', [ 'ngMaterial' ]);

})()
```

ChartController.js

```
(function(){
    angular.module('charts')
    .controller('ChartController', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

    }]);
})();
```

E o erro que aparece é esse:

> Error: [$injector:modulerr] 
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/modulerr?p0=starterApp&p1=%5B%24injector%3Amodulerr%5D%20http%3A%2F%2Ferrors.angularjs.org%2F1.3.15%2F%24injector%2Fmodulerr%3Fp0%3Dcharts%26p1%3D%255B%2524injector%253Anomod%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.3.15%252F%2524injector%252Fnomod%253Fp0%253Dcharts%250AR%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A444%253A417%250AOd%252F%253C%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A459%253A412%250Aa%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A459%253A53%250AOd%252F%253C%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A459%253A1%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A473%253A46%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A445%253A300%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A472%253A399%250Ag%252F%253C%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A473%253A63%250Ar%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A445%253A300%250Ag%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A472%253A399%250Aab%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A476%253A135%250Auc%252Fd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A455%253A381%250Auc%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A456%253A179%250AJd%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A455%253A1%250A%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A688%253A429%250An.Callbacks%252Fj%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A2%253A26920%250An.Callbacks%252Fk.fireWith%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A2%253A27738%250A.ready%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A2%253A29530%250AI%2540http%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A8080%252Ftarget%252Fjs%252Fgenerated-all.js%253A2%253A29721%250A%0AR%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A444%3A417%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A473%3A320%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A445%3A300%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A472%3A399%0Ag%2F%3C%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A473%3A63%0Ar%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A445%3A300%0Ag%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A472%3A399%0Aab%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A476%3A135%0Auc%2Fd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A455%3A381%0Auc%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A456%3A179%0AJd%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A455%3A1%0A%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A688%3A429%0An.Callbacks%2Fj%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A2%3A26920%0An.Callbacks%2Fk.fireWith%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A2%3A27738%0A.ready%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A2%3A29530%0AI%40http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2Ftarget%2Fjs%2Fgenerated-all.js%3A2%3A29721%0A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linha que carrega o chart.js e o chartController.js está comentada

```
<!-- 
 <script src="./src/charts/Charts.js"></script>
 <script src="./src/charts/ChartController.js"></script> 
-->
```

E logo em seguida tem um Javascript que tenta injetar o módulo chart.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  angular
      .module('starterApp', ['ngMaterial', 'charts']) // <- Está tentando injetar o módulo
      .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $mdIconProvider){

          /* $mdIconProvider
              .defaultIconSet("./assets/svg/avatars.svg", 128)
              .icon("menu"       , "./assets/svg/menu.svg"        , 24)
              .icon("share"      , "./assets/svg/share.svg"       , 24)
              .icon("google_plus", "./assets/svg/google_plus.svg" , 512)
              .icon("hangouts"   , "./assets/svg/hangouts.svg"    , 512)
              .icon("twitter"    , "./assets/svg/twitter.svg"     , 512)
              .icon("phone"      , "./assets/svg/phone.svg"       , 512); */

              $mdThemingProvider.theme('default')
                  .primaryPalette('brown')
                  .accentPalette('red');

      });

</script>
```

Tire o comentário e tenta de novo.

Comment: Afffff... o touchpad do meu notebook ta meio loco e isso fez com que fique colando código sem eu saber... semana toda isso me atrapalhando!
Bom que teve uma outra pessoa para ajudar!

Muito obrigado!